# Is there any way to limit the title in cakephp 2.3 find conditions

Tags: cakephp-2.1

lets say my table is blogs which contains (id, title, user_id, created, modified)
and i want to display all the blogs in drop down, so i run the following find condition,

```
$this->Blog->find('list',array('fields' => array('Blog.id','Blog.title'), 'conditions' => array('Blog.user_id' => $user_id)));
```

I want to limit the title to lets say 50 character in the above statement.
Don't want to do the loop over result then using substr function of php need the sql way to limit the title. Can any buddy help?.

Answer (score 0):

[CakePHP virtual fields are your friends](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html). For SQL query, [SUBSTR](http://sql.sh/fonctions/substring) will do.

You can declare a virtual field in your Blog Model:
public $virtualFields = array('short_title' => 'SUBSTR(Blog.title, 1 , 50)');

Then in your find you search for Blog.short_title instead of Blog.title.

Comment: Thanks chris but i was looking for query based solution thal is for model based, well thanks for your help.